# Visual Studio 2012, Unable to launch the IIS Express Webserver, Webmatrix and command line ok

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

When trying to change the project url for my MVC 4 web app, i got some weird error.
So first what i did:

Changed Project Url from

```
    http://localhost:54300 to http://192.168.1.26:54300
```

Changed the bindingInformation for my site to

```
    *:54300:192.168.1.25:54300
```

Added address:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.26:54300/ user=everyone
```

So when i am trying to run my web app from visual studio i get the error

```
"Unable to launch the ISS Express Web Server"
```

When running my web app from Webmatrix or if i start IIS express from command line, everything works.
What i've tried: Reinstall visual studio, but no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that `netsh` stuff for HTTPS? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: Not only for https, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Start your project using the Visual Studio Development  Server and see if it works. If it does then it means its a configuration problem. Close Visual Studio, back up or rename the %USER_HOME%\Documents\IISExpress folder. Re start Visual Studio again and open your application. Right Click your application and select Use IISExpress.

Hope it helps.